# Proving that a product of 2 complete residue systems of modulo p is not complete (modulo p)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given that $p$ is a prime and $p>2$ and let $a_1, \ldots , a_p$ and  $b_1, \ldots , b_p$  be two complete systems of residues modulo $p$ where $a_p \equiv b_p \equiv 0 \pmod p$. Prove
that $a_1b_1, \ldots , a_pb_p$ is not a complete system of residues modulo $p$.

hint: Wilson Theorem

I can't even grasp why it is not a complete system of residues, because by definition if $p\mid a_p$ and $p\mid b_p$ then the condition $p\mid a_pb_p$  must arise, so how come it is not a complete system? I am thinking that maybe my comprehension of system\class of residues is wrong...

Comment: Please see my edit to learn some MathJax features.

Comment: What does Wilson Theorem say, first of all? You won't get far if you don't use the hint. Please include that in the question, try using it and **then** say where you are stuck.

Comment: Using the Wilson is pointless at this stage because I can't  even comprehend what I am trying to proof.And why this proof(that the product is not complete sys. of residues) by itself is "true"

Comment: It's not pointless, write it down and try to figure out how it is related to the problem. Take $p=3$ and see what happens. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) on what to do when you have no clue on a question.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier For a1b1; a2b2; : : : ; apbp to be a complete
system of residues modulo p under the assumption that ap ≡ bp ≡ 0 (mod p)
it must be that
(a1b1) · (a2b2) · · · (ap−1bp−1) ≡ (p − 1)! ≡ −1 (mod p); 
by Wilson’s theorem. To show that a1b1; a2b2; : : : ; apbp does not form a
complete system of residues we show that (8.67) does not hold. Indeed, by
Wilson’s theorem we have that
a1 · a2 · · · ap−1 ≡ b1 · b2 · · · bp−1 ≡ −1 (mod p):
Hence,
(a1b1) · (a2b2) · · · (ap−1bp−1) ≡ (−1)2 ≡ 1 (mod p):
As p > 2 we have that −1 6≡ 1 (mod p). The claim follows.

Comment: Wow! you went from not seeing the point at all to a complete understanding of the problem in no time! Congrats :) dunno where (8.67) comes from though.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier -_- you are kidding right...? I am trying to explain that the solution is pointless because I don't understand the claim in the exeresice... the solution from the book(all copyrights go to it©)

Comment: I don't know how it was supposed to be clear that this last post was not by yourself. If you don't understand this proof you should include it in the question and explain what it is that you don't understand because it's crystal clear to me.

Comment: forget it......

Comment: ""I can't even grasp why it is not a complete system of residues, because by definition if p∣ap and p∣bp then the condition p∣apbp must arise,"  Um... There are other elements than $a_p$.  $p \not\mid a_i$ and $p\not \mid b_i$ for $a_1..... a_{p-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residue classes modulo $p$ form a field. As such every element $a$ in a complete residue system, disregarding $0$, has a multiplicative inverse $a^{-1}$. Note these $a$ and $a^{-1}$ are distinct from each other, consider why this is true, apart from the two elements $1$ and $p-1\equiv-1\pmod{p}$, which are self inverse, also understand why this is true. Note also $(p-1)\cdot 1\equiv-1\pmod{p}$ (from which Wilson's Theorem, $(p-1)!\ \equiv \ -1\pmod {p}$, follows  after some work).

Assuming $a_p \equiv b_p \equiv 0 \pmod p$, then since 
$$a_1\cdot a_2 \dotsm a_{p-1}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$$
and 
$$b_1\cdot b_2 \dotsm b_{p-1}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$$
by Wilson's Theorem. Now form the product
$$
(a_1\cdot a_2 \dotsm a_{p-1})\cdot (b_1\cdot b_2 \dotsm b_{p-1})\equiv-1\cdot-1=1\pmod{p}
$$
so
$$
(a_1b_1)\cdot (a_2 b_2)\dotsm (a_{p-1} b_{p-1})\equiv 1\pmod{p}
$$
so what does this tell us about the system $a_1b_1$, $a_2 b_2,\dotsc, a_{p-1} b_{p-1}$, $a_pb_p$?

Comment: putting it in that sense it's clear to me now that it contracdicts the theorem! thank you!

Comment: That's correct. Have a look at the proof of Wilson's Theorem and see how $(p-1)!$ and the product $a_1\cdot a_2 \dotsm a_{p-1}$ relate to each other, it's all in the inverses.

Answer (score 2):

If $m$ is a positive integer, a complete residue system, mod $m$, is a set of $m$ integers, which, when reduced mod $m$, is equal (as a set) to the set of integers between $0$ and $m-1$ inclusive.

For example, the sets $\{-3,1,14,8,-20\}$ and $\{7,6,13,35,-1\}$ are both complete residue systems, mod $5$.

Now recall Wilson's Theorem: If $p$ is prime, then $(p-1)!\equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;p)$.

For the question at hand . . .

Let $p$ be an odd prime.

Suppose $a_1,...,a_p$ and $b_1,...,b_p$ are complete residue systems, mod $p$, with $a_p$ and $b_p$ both congruent to zero, mod $p$,

Then the sequences $a_1,...,a_{p-1}$ and $b_1,...,b_{p-1}$, reduced mod $p$, are permutations of $1,...,p-1$, hence, by Wilson's Theorem,
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}a_k\equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;p)
\\
\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}b_k\equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;p)
$$
which implies
$$\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}a_kb_k\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;p)$$
hence, since $p$ is odd,
$$\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}a_kb_k\not\equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;p)$$
so by Wilson's Theorem, the sequence $a_1b_1,...,a_{p-1}b_{p-1}$, reduced mod $p$, is not a permutation of $1,...,p-1$.

Then, since $a_pb_p$ is congruent to zero, mod $p$, it follows that  $a_1b_1,...,a_pb_p$ is not a complete residue system, mod $p$.

Comment: I don't think that's helping the OP to do it all for them where they couldn't even see how Wilson was related to the problem.

Comment: In this case, short of a private chat, my sense was that hints would not be sufficient.

Comment: Apparently they were, given the OP's last comment :)

Comment: Yep, the OP transformed! I'll delete my answer (in favor of yours).

Comment: Oh, so the OP's comment was a book solution! Hence, I'll reinstate my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how that was supposed to be obvious, or what the point of it was...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Wilson's theorem says that

> **IF** $x_1,\ldots, x_{p-1}$ is a complete residue system except that it doesn't contain $0$, **THEN** (something happens)

What you want to prove is that

> (some set) is **NOT** a residue system.

The relation between the two is obvious: use **proof by contradiction**.

*If* the stated set was a residue system, *then* (we could apply Wilson's theorem).

On the way you are going to need to apply Wilson's theorem to both residue systems $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint to help your understanding:

$p|a_p$ and $p|b_p$ but $p\not\mid a_i$ and $p\not\mid b_i$ for $i \ne p$.

If we do this $\mod 3$ and let $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\} = \{1,2, 3\}$ be a complete residue system. And $\{b_1,b_2,b_3\} = \{4,5,6\}$ also be a complete residue system.

Then we get $\{a_1b_1, a_2b_2, a_3b_3\} = \{4, 10, 18\}$.  Is that a complete residue system?

Notice that $a_1b_1 \equiv a_2b_2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $a_ib_i  \equiv 2 \mod 3$ can never happen for any $i$. So we have *two* residues that are congruent to $1$ and *zero* residues that are congruent to $2$.

So, no, it is not complete.

Wilson's theorem states that $a_1a_2\equiv (3-1)!  \equiv -1 \mod 3$ and that $b_1b_2 \equiv (3-1)! \equiv -1 \mod 3$.  And, what do you know, $a_1a_2 = 1*2 = 2!\equiv -1 \mod 3$ and $b_1*b_2=4*5 = 20\equiv 2 =2!\equiv -1 \mod 3$.  So that is true.

If $\{a_ib_i\}$ were a complete residue theorem we would have $(a_1b_1)*(a_2b_2) \equiv -1 \mod 3$.

Does it?

$(a_1b_1)*(a_2*b_2) \equiv 4*10\equiv 40=39+1 \equiv 1 \mod 3$.  And $1 \not \equiv -1\mod 3$.

So this is not a complete residue system.

Not only could we tell by examing it directly, we could also tell by using Wilson's theorem.

...

Can we do the same for any other  prime $p>$?  Oh, and will this be true for *other* residue systems?

....

One more hint:  $(a_1b_2)*(a_2*b_2)\equiv (a_1a_2)(b_1b_2) \equiv (-1)*(-1)\mod 3$.